# Without using store procedure, is there any way that we can control Constraints of return Qty over the total Qty in OrderLine (MySQL)?

Tags: mysql, sql

Ok, generally, an order system will have these tables:

```
1. Order table

OrderID - OrderDate....
2 - 12/11/2014
...


2.OrderLine table

OrderLineID - OrderID - Item ID - ItemName - Total Qty....
2 - 2 - 5 - iPhone - 3 
....

3. Return table

ReturnID - OrderLineID - Return Qty
2 - 2 - 1
```

Look at the above table we saw the customer generated an order (orderID=2), he bought 3 iPhone (OrderLineID=2 with total Qty=3), but then later he returned 1.

My question is, for the same OrderLine, can we force the Return Qty column in Return table must be <= TotalQty column in OrderLine Table. For ex, in the above example, if someone inserts the Return Qty=4 in return table for orderline=2, the system will generate an constraint error.

```
ReturnID - OrderLineID - Return Qty
2 - 2 - 4 --> system should generate an error cos 4 >3
```

In Return table, we control the foreign key by using `add foreign key (orderLineID) references OrderLine(orderLineID)`
But then how can we do the similar thing for the return Qty without using Stored procedure?

Comment: *But then how can we do the similar thing for the return Qty without using Stored procedure?* If by this you mean how can you do this declaratively rather than programmatically then answer is you can't. Options are: 1) do this check in your client code, 2) do this check in a stored procedure which you presumably call from your client code, 3) do it with a trigger

Answer (score 0):

You need to create 2 **triggers** to validate the Return Qty column:
`BEFORE INSERT` and `BEFORE UPDATE`. Take a look at this article http://cvuorinen.net/2013/05/validating-data-with-triggers-in-mysql/